# Python WSGI ignoring python-home virtual environment?

Tags: python, python-3.6, wsgi

Using WSGI with Python 3.6 on RHEL 8 to run Flask on Apache.

In the WSGI configuration, we have the following line:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess myapp user=apache group=apache threads=5 python-home=/var/www/FLASKAPPS/myapp/venv
```

When activating the virtual environment and running the Flask application from the command line, the application works fine in the test server.

When connecting through Apache, the error_log records that modules that are in the venv can't be loaded.

NOTE: I have seen some other questions on this topic, but they all seem to be about using a different version of Python than the version used to set up WSGI. In my case, the WSGI module is for Python 3.6 as far as I can tell.

Answer (score -1):

If apache refuses to use modules in the virtualenv, you can always install the module on the system directly (i.e. not inside the virtualenv) -- this seems not like a very attractive solution. Alternatively, You could try something different like uwsgi, gunicorn, etc. or put everything into a docker container then you don't feel the pain of installing your python modules directly into the system.